# How do I run a Perl script in the background on Windows?

Tags: perl, winapi, background, process

I have a Perl script that pops up a message box when its work is done. How can I run this in the background?

I looked at [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-Background), but this requires launching a specific command. I'd like my code to run in the background without spawning a new process if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to run the program with `wperl`, the Windows GUI version, instead of `perl`.

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I need since this is a simple program manually launched from the commandline.

Comment: Can you elaborate? E.g. will it display a GUI window or just be invisible? A demonstration by way of sample use (actual command line/from the *Run* dialog - say with a Perl one-liner for something that takes a few seconds to execute). Some screenshots (if it applies). What version of Perl and which Perl was it tried with.

Answer (score 2):

Consider running it as a service. There is a Perl script located [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=230377)
which will actually install it for you.

Alternatively, you could also try [ExeService](https://slion.net/view/Dev/ExeService), a program which allows you to run executables, scripts, and commands as Windows services.

For further information on what a windows service is, see
*[Windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)* (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl 5.x, use [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html). Fork is a built-in keyword and supported across all platforms.

Here is some sample code:

*[Re: Perl Background processes in Windows](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663272)*

Comment: Er, I think you'll find FORK isn't available on Windows as it's a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Win32::GUI; 
BEGIN {
    Win32::GUI::Hide(scalar(Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow()))
};
```

This will make your script work in the background